# What will happen if there is no spontaneous emission in laser? Will the working of the laser be possible?

Tags: laser

We can use the Einstein's coefficients and omit the spontaneous term. How do I proceed after that?

Comment: Laser light always begins as a spontaneous emission. The light is spontaneous emission amplified by dint of stimulated emission. Not *all* spontaneous emission in a laser is amplified in this way: a resonant cavity chooses which direction and wavelength the "seed" spontaneous emission has to be for amplification to happen.

Answer (score 3):

The Einstein coefficients are related.

In SI units
$$ A_{21} = \frac{8\pi h\nu^3}{c^3} B_{21},$$
where $\nu$ is the frequency and $A_{21}$ and $B_{21}$ are the spontaneous and stimulated emission coefficients.

Thus I think the answer is that if the spontaneous emission coefficient is zero, then so is the stimulated emission coefficient and hence no laser.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamical point of view: below threshold, the only stable solution for a laser is $I=0$. At and above threshold, $I=0$ is still a solution for the system, but it looses its stability, and another solution with $I>0$ becomes stable. Above threshold, the system can fall out of the unstable solution $I=0$ (and land on the new stable one $I>0$)  only if noise is present, noise being spontaneous emission. Without spontaneous emission, the laser would never switch on.